# Redshift spectrum - Updating external spectrum table column type

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I've created an external table having 4 columns.
One of the column is of custom datatype.

```
create EXTERNAL table public.test_table_1(
uuid varchar(36),
event_id varchar(36),
last_updated_timestamp bigint,
user_app struct<starttime : int, endtime : int, id_1 : struct<value : float>>
```

I want to update the column `user_app` to a new datatype of formar:

```
struct<starttime : int, endtime : int, id_1 : struct<value : float>, id_2 : struct<value : float>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about dropping the table, and creating it anew with the correct column type?

Since it's an external table, you will not loose any date upon dropping it.

```
DROP TABLE public.test_table_1;

create EXTERNAL table public.test_table_1(
    uuid varchar(36),
    event_id varchar(36),
    last_updated_timestamp bigint,
    user_app struct<
        starttime : int, 
        endtime : int, 
        id_1 : struct<value : float>, 
        id_2 : struct<value : float>
     >
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using Glue data catalog.

Navigate to Glue data catalog --> Tables --> Edit Schema

Click on struct data type for column user_map and update the definition.

[As shown in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHWNt.png)